# Would like to put a Calender on Cloud

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to put a calender on our Cloud so that our small team is able to connect wherever they are in the world. Ideally it would be good if it could be the calender from Thunderbird. I am not the tech person just a screen gnome and our man is currently deep under the flu. Any suggestions to an illiterate like me would be welcomed. Jack.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Thunderbird's lightning plugin, which syncs with Google Calender.

You can create one common Gmail ID which you can share with other users. If you need any support in setting the things please let us know.

Comment: I totally agree, but I would rather use Google Apps in stead of a common Google account.